# My count CTE returning blanks, how can I get it return as 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

CTE created to count the number of days left from today's date to end of current month. So my report for today (30 March 2021) did not count tomorrow's date 31 March 2021.

```
   declare @DespatchTo Date = '03-30-2021'

   WITH mycte AS
    (
      SELECT CAST(Convert(date,getdate()) AS DATETIME) DateValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  DateValue + 1
      FROM    mycte   
      WHERE   DateValue  < DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @DespatchTo) + 1, 0)) --03-31-2021
    )
    
    SELECT SUN.Count as SunCount, SAT.Count as SatCount, WK.Count as WeekCount
    FROM 
    (SELECT  count(*) as Count
    FROM    mycte
    WHERE DatePart("w",DateValue) = 1
    group by DatePart("w",DateValue))
    As SUN,
    
    (SELECT  count(*) as Count
    FROM    mycte
    WHERE DatePart("w",DateValue) = 7
    group by DatePart("w",DateValue))
    As SAT,
    
    (SELECT  distinct SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS Count
    FROM    mycte
    WHERE DatePart("w",DateValue) > 1 AND DatePart("w",DateValue) < 7
    group by DatePart("w",DateValue))
    As WK
```

Which returns blank/null results. How can I return as 0?

[image]

Comment: @GordonLinoff SQL Server, I run the query in ssrs though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you need to do:

```
;WITH mycte AS (
    SELECT  GETDATE() DateValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateValue + 1
    FROM mycte
    WHERE DateValue < EOMONTH(GETDATE())
)

select
   count(case when datepart(dw, DateValue) = 1 then 1 end) SUN
 , count(case when datepart(dw, DateValue) = 7 then 1 end) SAT
 , count(case when datepart(dw, DateValue) between 2 and 6 then 1 end) WK
from mycte
```

if you want to exclude today, you can  adjust cte :

```
;WITH mycte AS (
    SELECT  GETDATE() + 1 DateValue
    WHERE GETDATE() <> EOMONTH(GETDATE())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateValue + 1
    FROM mycte
    WHERE DateValue < EOMONTH(GETDATE())
)

select
   count(case when datepart(dw, DateValue) = 1 then 1 end) SUN
 , count(case when datepart(dw, DateValue) = 7 then 1 end) SAT
 , count(case when datepart(dw, DateValue) between 2 and 6 then 1 end) WK
from mycte
```

Comment: for some reason on today. its giving me 4 more days for a wk day?

Comment: The between number of days was not right. See updated answer

Comment: Thanks its fixed, I have a question, when I have the date as the 03-31-2021, it gives a count of 1 for week day but it should be 0?

Comment: well it depends on hat you want , they query above shows for the given date untill end of month how many days are falling in weekdays , Sundays and Saturdays , for 03-31-2021, it is a weekday , do 1 for that , if you want to exclude today date , you can do it in cte